# Playstation Online Store & D.M.R.ights

Tags: ps3, psn

DMR. *Digital Media Rights* - correct?

If you own a PS4 and download full games on the PS.Store, like I have for at least three games I've purchased. When does that ownership expire? The answer should be never, since I paid for them. But I want to know the details...

Are they locked to the Playstation Network ID? If I sell my Ps4 in 10 years. And buy another 10 years later. **Can I simply login on a new Ps4, and have my games?**

10 years is long. By then something like Witcher 3 will be a full remake remodel hologram made out of chrome by then. So lets say 3 years.

Comment: Nope, Digital Rights Management. As in the rights of the company that owns the IP.

Comment: There is no ownership. You "own" the rights to PLAY thr game, effectivley, but do not own the game, itself. It is for this reason Sony may impose restrictions such as not letting you give the game to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Games you buy through PSN are locked to your account. They're yours forever to keep and download on any Playstation where you're logged in, as long as your account is in good standing and PSN exists. However, Sony reserves the right to remove your access to a game you bought if they deem it necessary. They also won't issue a refund if that happens.

Comment: PSN is different from PSPlus correct? The PSN will be mine if I dont login for years to come? (Im waiting for chrome Witcher 3)